# Updated to Version 5.57.0 from 5.56.1. Profile contact form now returns a "There has been a critical error on this website."

Tags: wordpress, contacts, error

Updated to Version 5.57.0 from 5.56.1.  Profile contact form now returns a "There has been a critical error on this website" page even though the new contact is captured.

#### wp-core ###. version: 6.0.3

#### wp-active-theme ###. name: Divi (Divi) version: 4.19.4

I received the following from my webhost TMD:

We would like to inform you, that upon our investigation, we've found the following error in the error log of your application:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Html2Text\Html2Text::getText() in /home/seedsave/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/String.php:452 Stack trace: #0 /home/seedsave/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail.php(188): CRM_Utils_String::htmlToText('<!DOCTYPE html ...')

#1 /home/seedsave/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/MessageTemplate.php(428): CRM_Utils_Mail::send(Array)
#2 /home/seedsave/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php(2704): CRM_Core_BAO_MessageTemplate::sendTemplate(Array)
#3 /home/seedsave/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Form.php(1300): CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::commonSendMail('28', Array)
#4 /home/seedsave/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Form/Edit.php(249): CRM_Profile_Form->postProcess()
#5 /home/seedsave/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(573): CRM_Profile_Form_Edit->postProcess()
#6 /home/seedsave/public_html/w in /home/seedsave/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/String.php on line 452

Despite our willingness to assist you with this issue, it appears to be related to the code of the application, which is not our area of expertise.